# Error al configurar imágenes del splashscreen en Cordova

Tags: cordova, splash

Tengo un problema a la hora de compilar:

> Error: Source path does not exist: platforms/android/res/screen/android/3.jpg

Las imágenes las tengo en: `platforms/android/res/screen/android/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en tu `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="3.jpg" density="port-xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Asi lo tengo, pero nada

Comment: Haz intentado sacar la imagen de esa ruta y dejarla en la raiz de tu proyecto? Edito mi respuesta

Comment: Listo. Gracias por la ayuda. Ahora solo se queda la pantalla en negro y no muestra las imagenes

Comment: Que raro! Si tu imagen es valida no deberia mostrar en negro, yo generalmente ocupo png para el splash, puedes dejar tu imagen para probar en uno de mis proyectos?

Comment: Listo gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si en algun futuro tienes imagenes distintas para cada resolucion, te aconsejo que crees una carpeta para guardar todas esas imagenes y reemplaces las rutas!  Saludos!

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que tienes las imágenes del splash screen en un directorio no accesible. Yo uso el plugin de cordova-plugin-splashscreen y tengo las imágenes en mi directorio `www/img`, entonces en el config.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/img/splash/splash.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Y me funciona sin problemas.